# Using querybuilder and joins with user table not calling accessor and mutator in Laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I am using querybuilder for my query and user table is used with join in other table.so I am not calling model directly like

`User::get()` method

so it is not calling

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
    }
```

How can I call this method with other model and join used for user model?

**EDIT 1:**

I have tried below

```
->with([
   'createdBy' => function($query) {
        $query->selectRaw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS full_name");
   }
]);
 public function createdBy() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'created_by', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: This is how accessors work. It only works when you are using the model instance.

Comment: @apokryfos so if I create accessor in other model and getFullNameAttribute in that other model will work?

Comment: Having a fullname attribute in your other model just for the cases where you join with the user model feels like bad practice. You would not normally use joins when working with models you'd instead use eloquent relationships

Comment: @apokryfos Do you have any solution for joins?

Comment: @apokryfos because eloquent is slower than query builder

Comment: A model is mean to represent a row in a single table. If you pollute it with additional columns then it's not intended use. This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You found eloquent to be slower than the query builder so now you are trying to get the query builder to work in ways it's not intended to instead of trying to find out why the eloquent is slower for you because when used correctly getting relationships via eloquent is the same or faster than using a join

Comment: @apokryfos I have edited question, tried with() but not working

Comment: when you have the relationship you just do `with('createdBy')` and when you get the model you can do `$otherModel->createdBy->fullName` since `createdBy` would be an instance of the User model. No need for the additional query in the `with`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something in a query, you can use [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) but I wouldn't use it in a join as @apokryfos said.

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function scopeFullName($query)
    {
        return $query->selectRaw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS full_name");
    }
}
```

```php
$yourQuery->fullName()->someOtherMethod();
```

Comment: Do I need to create this method in my User model or other model?

Comment: It has to be in the User model

Comment: I have edited question, tried with() but not working

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is the resulting query if you `YourModel::dd()->furtherQueryMethods();`